# How to delete the value inside the array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to delete the ['Phone'] inside my array.

i tried foreach and unset but only the first array delete the ['Phone'].

my example array below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => ads
            [Phone] => 32132
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => ads
            [Phone] => 321322
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => ads
            [Phone] => 3213222
        )

)
```

and my expected array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => ads
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => ads          
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => ads  
        )

)
```

Comment: You can loop over the outer array, using a foreach, and then `unset` the 'phone' part

Comment: Please use only related product tags - This question has nothing to do with `json` nor `laravel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_walk`

```
array_walk($arr, function(&$v, $k){
  unset($v['Phone']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to fetch the names, you can just pluck those using `array_column()`.

```
$array = array_column($array, "Name");
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/VJTli

Comment: it work, but i want to remain the ['Name']. how can I do that?

Comment: If you want to retain the structure and indexing, you can loop or map over the array and unset the values.

Comment: Or intersect or array_diff them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` function of Laravel Collection. and alter your original array however you want.

```php
$newArray = collect($oldArray)->map(function($element) {
    return [
        'name' => $element['name'];
    ];
})->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Qirel's answer is faster I would imagine if you only have "name" and "phone".  Another alternative that is easy on the eyes is:

```php
foreach ($array as &$val) {
    unset($val["Phone"]);
}
```